# How to use urlparse in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my code for getting domain name from string:

```
domain = urlparse('http://www.example.test/foo/bar').netloc
print(domain)
>>>www.example.test
```

I don't know how to use this method in pandas. Here is my pandas dataframe:

```
          domain
http://www.example.test/foo/bar
http://robotichairrx.com/
http://naturally-yours-hair-co.business.site/
```

I tried this code but didn't work:

```
df['domain'] = urlparse(df['domain']).netloc
```

getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `urlparse` does not accept a series as argument

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M then  any idea how to get domain name from my domain column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `Series.apply`

```
df['domain'] = df['domain'].apply(lambda domain: urlparse(domain).netloc)
```

Comment: Thanks it's working Abdul Niyas P M. can you please little bit explain what is  'lambda' doing here?

Comment: @boyenec `apply` [invoke a function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) on values of a Series(In this case it's `df['domain']`)